# The PE version of minecraft

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

The PE of Minecraft now has like a server name and IP address does that mean we can join computers and play?

Comment: This is a typical question that can be answered through Google or other, already-answered questions (even on this site).

Comment: This is a useful 4-step guide for setting up a PE server: http://www.instructables.com/id/How-To-Make-A-Minecraft-PE-Server/

Answer (score 2):

No, servers for Pocket Edition are separate.